# Stack Overflow Collectives: The article propose popover is positioned absolutely behind the sticky header

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, design, collectives

In [Stack Overflow Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws?tab=articles), the "Article Propose Popover" popover, which display:

> Simply submit a proposal, get it approved by a Recognized Member, and publish it.
> See how the process works

appears to be positioned using absolute positioning. And when using the Google Chrome web browser on a Mac, it has been noticed that the Article Propose Popover is situated behind what is referred to as the "sticky header."

The problem arises when the Article Propose Popover, which should ideally be visible and accessible to the user, is obscured by this sticky header. This can make it difficult or impossible for users to interact with or even see the contents of the popover, rendering it effectively unusable.

[image]

Comment: The popover should be aligned with the Collective page menu bar, so it's certainly out of place.  Does this happen every time you visit the collective's Articles page, or was it a one-off occurance?

Comment: Now that I have created an Article and which is review, the "Article Propose Popover" popover is not showing up. I assume it will show only for the users who never created an Article.